# mod_rewrite & .htaccess - redirect request for a file extension to a script

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I'd like to do is have requests for a given extension fowarded to a script with a query string.

Example...

`Requests for: http://mySite.com/myImage.png`

`Will be redirected to: http://mySite.com/imageServer.php?image=myImage.png`

Thanks for you help on this one, I'm no good at mod_rewrite or even regular expressions, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule will rewrite (internal redirect) all requests for **ANY** .png file to `/imageServer.php?image=<file-name.png>`.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (.+\.png)$ /imageServer.php?image=$1 [NC,L]
```

If you need this to be the actual redirect (301 Permanent redirect, when URL changes in browser), then add `R=301` to the rewrite rule flags, e.g. `[NC,L,R=301]`.

Comment: That's great thanks, I think I should also put the full path to the script in there because I'm dealing with everchanging path structure in the requests. You get best answer.. Nice one!

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  imageServer.php?image=$1
```

but it will rewrite  everything to new URL! you can put conditions on it!