# Write an existing PDF file, when the user directly call the .pdf extension?

Tags: php, pdf

I can write text in the pdf file with using code at [web site link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299315/writing-drawing-over-a-pdf-template-document-in-php)

If user enter the xxx.com/sample.php .. link shows the manipulated pdf file in the php page.

To make a manipulation we need to call PHP page.

If user directly enter the xxx.com/SAMPLE.pdf .. link shows the original pdf file...

How can I write the PDF file, when the user directly call the .pdf extension?

Should I write special code in the httpdocs file ?

For Example;
If user call .pdf extension from special directory like directory/SAMPLE.pdf
execute the special function to process pdf file.

How do I solve this problem ?

I thank you for your interest in my question.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use htaccess to redirect all requests to "folder/whatever.pdf" to "folder/pdfgenerator.php?file=whatever.pdf".

This way you can do anything you want in PHP, including generating the file before showing it or naming it "whatever.pdf" which you can get by using $_GET["file"] in the example I described.

There is a similar question here: [mod_rewrite & .htaccess - redirect request for a file extension to a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080996/mod-rewrite-htaccess-redirect-request-for-a-file-extension-to-a-script)

In your case it would be something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.+\.pdf)$ /pdfgenerator.php?file=$1 [NC,L]
```